# How to conditionally set a [disabled] attribute value in an Angular Reactive Form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

In an `Angular` `reactive form`, we have a checkbox which is required to be checked before our `save` button will work. Now, we have a new requirement to only display this checkbox to certain regions, which is easily accomplished via an `environment` property and an `*ngIf` on the checkbox.

However, how do I conditionally make that `save` button's `[disabled]` attribute not care about the checkbox?

**my-component.component.html**

```
      <div *ngIf="isMyCheckboxRegion">
        <input [formControl]="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
        <label for="my-checkbox">Please check this box</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button validationgroup="SaveMyForm"
          (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="anotherFormGroup.invalid || myCheckbox.invalid">Save</button>
      </div>
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

    export class myComponent implements OnInit {
        public isMyCheckboxRegion = environment.isMyCheckboxRegion;
        public myCheckbox = FormControl('', Validators.requiredTrue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `Validators.requiredTrue` conditionally:

```
public myCheckbox = FormControl('', this.isMyCheckboxRegion ? Validators.requiredTrue : undefined);
```

As the validator is applied conditionally, `myCheckbox.invalid` should be `false` regardless of the checkbox's value.

---

**Alternative:**

You can also use `isMyCheckboxRegion` in the HTML:

```
<button 
 validationgroup="SaveMyForm"
 (click)="onSubmit()" 
 [disabled]="anotherFormGroup.invalid || (isMyCheckboxRegion && myCheckbox.invalid)"
>Save</button>
```